# Помогите добавить Form2

Tags: c#

Здраствуйте, не могу добавить Form2 на C#
[image: тупо не нахожу Form2]

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Что именно нажимаете, что не так? СЛишком мало информации.

Comment: Просто не могу найти Form2 для своего проекта, я не знаю с чем это связано, окно авторизации я уже написал и хочу сделать переход от Form1 к Form2 но тупо не могу найти его

Comment: Гм. То есть вы не знаете пишете на winfoms или на wpf?

Comment: Типо того, я только начинаю

Answer (score 2):

Вобщем, раз начинающий, то советую создать проэкт заново, проследить что бы проэкт был наверняка  Winforms. А тогда уже пытаться добавить новую форму(кроме основной)

В WPF не лезь пока что.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да я и не собирался туда лезть, типо я по гайдам сечяс все делал но у чела есть Form2 а у меня нету

Comment: создей проэкт заново.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего тип проекта другой, вот нужный[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]